# Does a research competition with monetary prizes count as commerical use?

Tags: legal-issues, license

There are some datasets (bioinformatics, agriculture, weather, etc.) that state that they can only be used for non-commercial purposes. This would mean a corporation cannot take that dataset and use it in some way to make money. However, the phrase "for non-commercial use only" seems to be vague when it comes to monetary prizes (in the thousands of US dollars) from research competitions.

Can datasets that have this "for non-commercial use only" requirement be used in academic research that could *possibly* win money at a competition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer and this is not a legal advice.*

In general, this depends on at least the following factors:

- particular text of the formal license under which the dataset is provided
- the laws of the country where the parties (licensor and licensee) reside
- definitions that are used to determine whether the activity is considered to be *commercial* or *non-commercial* if the actual license text is unclear about it
- status of the organization where the research is conducted

However, usually, the *commercial purpose* has the connotation of **direct** income generated from the goods or services produced with the help of the licensed content. In the case of the research work that **happen** to win a certain competition, I would argue that would not be considered a **direct** income. Thus, should constitute *non-commercial* use.

From the [Creative Commons study on non-commercial use](https://creativecommons.org/2009/09/14/defining-noncommercial-report-published/), the following definition of the *commercial* use is very common:

> … in any manner that is primarily intended for or directed toward commercial advantage or private monetary compensation.

I would argue that no academic research has the **primary** goal of monetary compensation. Winning in the competition for an academic researcher usually is "collateral damage".

---

To reiterate,

1. The definition of *commercial* and *non-commercial* use is license-specific; therefore, without the text of the license, it is impossible to determine whether a certain way of using the licensed content is legal or not.
2. If in doubt, consult a lawyer or use the legal services that most educational institutions provide.
3. The use for academic research that might/did win a competition is very likely to be within the *non-commercial* use clause of the license.

Comment: I would not be so sure about your "primary goal" distinction. [Wikipedia does not accept material from non-commercial-use licenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:FAQ/Copyright#Non-commercial_licenses), for instance, because the Wikimedia Foundation sells T-shirts, CD copies of Wikipedia etc. even though that is a small part of what they do. Maybe there is a distinction based on knowledge timing (i.e. if you use the NC dataset before knowing you will enter a competition you are off the hook) but it looks shaky at best (how would you prove that?).